# Semantic UI bypasses browser form messages

Tags: forms, dropdown, semantic-ui

I have a dropdown that is required for my form. Without Semantic UI everything works as expected. If the user doesn't select anything he gets a message "You must select an optino" or similar from the browser.

```
<select required>
     <option value="" selected="">Please select</option>
     <option value="True">Yes</option>
     <option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

As soon as I style my dropdown with Semantic UI this functionality disappears.

```
 <select class="ui search dropdown" required>
     <option value="" selected="">Please select</option>
     <option value="True">Yes</option>
     <option value="False">No</option>
 </select>
```

This seems to be because Semantic UI hides the original `select` and adds some bastardized select based on divs. However due to this some of the functionality described above is vanished.

Is there a workaround on this? I want to keep my forms working even with javascript disabled.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4uz1m53/2/).

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Pointed out on the issue, this is what you can do:

> Hi @[Pithikos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474563/pithikos), you’re correct about the cause of it not working. You could additionally use the [validation](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html) component that would be falling back to browser validation for clients with disabled JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that Semantic UI converts the `select` tag into some other HTML **including** an `input` tag. The problem is that it doesn't respect the `required` attribute so the new input tag ends up not having it.

Here's a workaround (after `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();`):

```
  $('.ui.dropdown').each(function(){
     $select = $(this).find('select');
     $input = $(this).find('input');
     if ($select.attr('required') && $input) {
         $input.attr('required', 'true');

         // Remove required attribute when user or browser focuses on
         // the input element and thus getting the selection menu. After
         // this event we assume there is a guarantee that the input has
         // a value.
         $('.ui.dropdown input').on('focus', function(e){
            $(this).removeAttr('required');
         });
     }
  });
```

The workaround works by adding the necessary `required` attribute. Once that input is focused we assume that a value has been selected and remove the `required` attribute.

Here's the [bug reported on github](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5365).